# Calculating each specific occurrence using value_counts() in Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataframe named `Tasks`, containing a column named `UserName`. I want to count every occurrence of a row containing the same UserName, therefore getting to know how many tasks a user has been assigned to. For a better understanding, here's how my dataframe looks like:

[image]

In order to achieve this, I used the code below:

`Most_Involved = Tasks['UserName'].value_counts()`

But this got me a DataFrame like this:

```
Index                  Username
John                   4
Paul                   1
Radu                   1
```

Which is not exactly what I am looking for. How should I re-write the code in order to achieve this:

**Most_Involved**

```
Index                  UserName               Tasks
0                      John                   4
1                      Paul                   1
2                      Radu                   1
```

Comment: Please don't share information as images unless absolutely necessary. See: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/303812. Also, variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `transform` to add a new column to existing data frame:

```
df['Tasks'] = df.groupby('UserName')['UserName'].transform('size')

# finally select the columns needed
df = df[['Index','UserName','Tasks']]
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for helping but I can't figure something out - which DataFrame is `df` in my case? Moreover, Where did the `['Tasks']` column come from? Thanks for your time and hopefully you'll be able to answer these concerns.

Comment: df is the `Tasks`data frame you have. We create a new column, I called it as `Tasks` you can name it anything, may be that's what caused confusion.

Answer (score 1):

you can find duplicate rows based on columns by using pandas.
duplicateRowsDF = dataframe[dataframe.duplicated(['columnName'])]

[here](https://thispointer.com/pandas-find-duplicate-rows-in-a-dataframe-based-on-all-or-selected-columns-using-dataframe-duplicated-in-python/) is the complete solution

Comment: Isn't there an easier way to do this? Using the `.duplicated` would ignore single occurrences and more code will be needed to also take care of those, I suppose.